# How to select $(this) AND $(this) > child with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this, css-selectors, parent-child

Can't quite figure this out. If I use:

```
$('> .someClass', this);
```

It will select `this > .someClass`, but I want to select `this` AND `this > child`

Tried

```
  $(this+'> .someClass', this);
//AND
 var currentEl = $(this);
  $(currentEl, currentEl+'> .someClass')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `andSelf()`

```
$(this).find('> .someclass').andSelf();
```

[andSelf() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) function to add `this` to the set of matched elements, like so:

```
$(this).find('> .someclass').andSelf();
```